# How to use Chrome extensions on PDF

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extensions

Google Chrome is able to read PDF files. My objective is to use acessibility extensions such as HyperBold, OpenDyslexic, High contrast.
But these extentions do not work when reading a PDF file, how I can solve this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Most of extensions work with HTML/CSS by default. At the very minimum you would need to rewrite them to work with PDFs, if that's even possible with Chrome's API.

Comment: Try the extension [Dyslexic Browser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dyslexic-browser/gflobokeglbgdhdelipppigfncpnfgbh).

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to modify much of the web page appearances via extenders, there is one area that is generally inaccessible, and that is an existing PDF body since it should not alter its appearance.

Here in a JS viewer of a TeX Built Article the surround has been altered to a ***Dyslexic Italic Bold*** font as seen on the right.

An Audio Accessibility reader is allowed to work on that PDF textract, however an appearance changer is not, especially as the visible text is simply pixels as a screen rendered binary image. I.E. the text is not really there its a prismatic image as seen through a lens (A smoke and mirrors chimera of a real PDF reader which will present the same image on screen, at the very most you might change rendered colours.)

[image]

To adapt a PDF to a different font you need to convert to HTML, alter by key press or default and reprint to PDF.

[image]
[image]